# Autosave on jsp page without using database

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a simple registration page and login in page.if user logs  in successfully can access the registration page. what i need is, consider he is in middle of the registration page if he bymistake close the browser or even the system crash down.the entried data may lost.i need to save(not database)  those filled contents to be populated when he logs in again.I dont want cokkie autocomplete.Any other option avaliable? and how about serialization will it be helpful?

Comment: If the application crashes down, you'll lose your backup anyway, and you'll have much more important problems to solve (like avoiding crashes). If he mistakenly closes his browser, then he should expect to lose the current form. That's what always happens. It's normal and expected. I wouldn't bother.

Comment: There are no other options.  You took all the options off the table.  Either you are going to store them locally in a cookie, which I think is a bad idea, or you will store them remotely on the server.  If the only issue with server-side is that you can't use a DB, then store it some other way, like a flat file (also not recommended, but not sure what the requirements are so hard to say) or keep it in-memory in Cache.

Comment: I am using ajax on every event for creating backup (using db).my database is on cloud (amazon).so even  my system cash down.I can get my saved data from cloud.But this is heavy wait>i need somehting like saving on one file and put it in cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use local storage instead of cookies or db:

HTML:

```
Login: <input class="inputField" id="login" type="text"/><br>
Name: <input class="inputField" id="name" type="text"/><br>
Phone: <input class="inputField" id="phone" type="text"/>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".inputField").each(function() {
        $(this).val(localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("id")));
    });
    $(".inputField").keyup(function() {
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
    });        
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CA98s/).

Comment: Hi.this looks good.but how can i acheive this on multi user login?content may vary according to logged in user.how to handle tat.

Comment: Maybe you could delete these localStorage items if the user logs in. I'm not sure I see your case completely.

Comment: Let me try it in my code and acknowledge you ASAP.thanks @Nailgun.

Comment: It didnt work man.the data is saved on page.if many user logs in .it shows same data. It will be heavy if i maintain all user data on localstorage